# Remove unwrap from vec pop

Tags: error-handling, rust

This is a function (that works) that produces a vector of things but there is some ugly unwrapping in there as it involves popping another vector.

```
fn load_into_vec(file_buf: String) -> Vec<Data> {

    let mut data_vec: Vec<Data> = Vec::new();

    for line_iter in file_buf.lines() {

        let mut line_vec: Vec<&str> = line_iter.split(' ').collect();

        let (t1, t2, t3, t4): (u32, u32, u32, u32) =
        (
            /** ANOTHER WAY TO WRITE THIS? **/
            line_vec.pop().unwrap().trim().parse::<u32>().ok().unwrap(),
            line_vec.pop().unwrap().trim().parse::<u32>().ok().unwrap(),
            line_vec.pop().unwrap().trim().parse::<u32>().ok().unwrap(),
            line_vec.pop().unwrap().trim().parse::<u32>().ok().unwrap()
        );

        let mut data_node = Data::new();
        data_node.load((t4, t3, t2, t1));
        data_vec.push(data_node);
    }

    data_vec
}
```

Is there was another way to rewrite the above block without using `unwrap` or to use `unwrap` in a way that it will not panic if it encounters `None`?

Comment: If making it look prettier is all you're after (and panic'ing).. maybe [something like this would be sufficient for you?](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=462d0e57bedae7a31381cee670ba6688&version=stable)

Comment: is there a way to call unwrap_or_else with a panic inside?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving code that **already works** better belong on [Code Review.SE](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterators and `match` to write a more idiomatic version of your loop body. Instead of collecting into an intermediate `Vec`, you match on calling `iter.next()` four times, to extract your four integers. In case one of the `iter.next()` calls doesn't succeed, you can panic.

```
    let mut iter = line_iter.split(' ')
        .map(str::trim)
        .map(str::parse::<u32>)
        .map(|s| s.expect("could not parse as u32"))
        .fuse();

    let tup = match (iter.next(), iter.next(), iter.next(), iter.next()) {
        (Some(t1), Some(t2), Some(t3), Some(t4)) => (t1, t2, t3, t4),
        _ => panic!("line did not contain at least four numbers"),
    };

    let mut data_node = Data::new();
    data_node.load(tup);
```

I would even go as far as to rewrite the entire function:

```
file_buf.lines()
    .map(|line_iter| {
        let mut iter = line_iter.split(' ')
            .map(str::trim)
            .map(str::parse::<u32>)
            .map(|s| s.expect("could not parse as u32"))
            .fuse();

        let tup = match (iter.next(), iter.next(), iter.next(), iter.next()) {
            (Some(t1), Some(t2), Some(t3), Some(t4)) => (t1, t2, t3, t4),
            _ => panic!("line did not contain at least four numbers"),
        };

        let mut data_node = Data::new();
        data_node.load(tup);
        data_node
    })
    .collect()
```

Even better would be to have the function return a `Result` that denotes when an error has occurred:

```
enum MyError {
    NotAnInt,
    TooFewNumbers,
    TooManyNumbers,
}

fn load_into_vec2(file_buf: String) -> Result<Vec<Data>, MyError> {
    file_buf.lines()
        .map(|line_iter| {
            let mut iter = line_iter.split(' ')
                .map(str::trim)
                .map(str::parse::<u32>)
                .fuse();

            match (iter.next(), iter.next(), iter.next(), iter.next()) {
                (Some(Ok(t1)), Some(Ok(t2)), Some(Ok(t3)), Some(Ok(t4))) => if iter.next().is_some() {
                    Err(MyError::TooManyNumbers)
                } else {
                    let mut data_node = Data::new();
                    data_node.load((t1, t2, t3, t4));
                    Ok(data_node)
                },
                (None, _, _, _) |
                (_, None, _, _) |
                (_, _, None, _) |
                (_, _, _, None) => Err(MyError::TooFewNumbers),
                (Some(Err(_)), _, _, _) |
                (_, Some(Err(_)), _, _) |
                (_, _, Some(Err(_)), _) |
                (_, _, _, Some(Err(_))) => Err(MyError::NotAnInt),
            }
        })
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: You know you shouldn't call `next` multiple times on an iterator without checking at each step or fusing it.

Comment: You're right of course. [We should clippy that, too](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/issues/1448)